# Using the subprocess module in python to run a lua script with command line inputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, lua, subprocess

I have a Lua script with command line inputs that I would like to run in Python (2.7) and read the output. For example the code I would run in terminal (Ubuntu 14.xx) looks like:

```
lua sample.lua -arg1 helloworld -arg2 "helloworld"
```

How do I run a Lua script with command line inputs in Python using the subprocess module? I think it would be something like this:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.check_output(['lua', '-l', 'sample'], 
    inputs= "-arg1 helloworld -arg2 "helloworld"")
print(result)
```

What is the right way to do this?

This is very similar to the link below but different in that I am trying to use command line inputs as well. The below question just calls a Lua function defined in the (Lua) script and feeds the inputs directly to that function. Any help would be very much appreciated.

[Run Lua script from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841738/run-lua-script-from-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't sure, you can generally pass the verbatim string that works in the shell and split it with `shlex.split`:

```
import shlex
subprocess.check_output(shlex.split('lua sample.lua -arg1 helloworld -arg2 "helloworld"'))
```

However, you *usually* don't need to do this and can just split the arguments by hand if you know what they are ahead of time:

```
subprocess.check_output(['lua', 'sample.lua', '-arg1', 'helloworld', '-arg2', 'helloworld'])
```

Comment: This worked for me and looks like the most complete answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import subprocess

print subprocess.check_output('lua sample.lua -arg1 helloworld -arg2 "helloworld"', shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this one and it didn't quite work. That might just be a function of my code though. Maybe it will help someone else who comes here