# Is there a way to run Lua scripts in Google App Engine (Python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, lua, lupa

I have a bunch of Lua scripts that I need to port to a Google App Engine application. Ideally I would like to be able to run those scripts within Python, either through and interpreter or with a wrapper/bridge like Lupa. Any ideas about how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Set up a separate micro service in App Engine Flex so that you can do this:

[Run Lua script from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841738/run-lua-script-from-python)